Torque at only two points of contact between a rope and a disk (rigid body dynamic)
In physics, particularly when dealing with rigid bodies, there's a common practice of calculating torque at only two points of contact between a rope and a rotating disk, typically at the extremes where the rope makes contact with the disk (these two tensions do not have the same modulus). Why is this approach commonly employed instead of considering torque at all points of contact between the rope and the disk? Is there a fundamental principle or simplification behind this convention, or are there specific scenarios where considering torque at only two points is sufficient for accurate analysis?

edit: I did not specify that the disk is rotating

Is the disk fixed or does it rotate?

The disk rotates.

Why should we treat the friction between the rope and the disk any differently from that between two flat contacting surfaces?

I think this difference stems from the dynamics of rotational motion. When a rope is wrapped around a disk, the points where the rope makes contact with the disk behave differently from two flat surfaces in contact. In rotational motion, these points of contact are crucial for determining the torque applied to the disk. Unlike flat surfaces, where friction may primarily affect linear motion, in the case of a rope and a rotating disk, friction at the points of contact contributes significantly to the rotational dynamics. Furthermore, my question concerns the tension of the rope and its torque.


Why is this approach commonly employed instead of considering torque at all points of contact between the rope and the disk?

Because it's simpler.
The torque on the the pulley comes from the friction of the rope.  As the friction is normal to the pulley surface, it is always tangential.  Therefore it doesn't matter along which portion of the rope the forces arise.  At any point on the circumference, the same magnitude force will apply the same torque about the axle.
For a light rope, the total tangential forces from the pulley must be equal to the difference in tension at each end of the pulley.   As long as that total force is applied and considered as torque, that is sufficient for the pulley's behavior.
